# На каком языке пишутся объектные файлы С++?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

На каком языке пишутся объектные файлы С++? Судя по прототипам, то хедеры на С++, но как же объектные файлы? Существуют те, которые имеют взаимодействие с ОС. Например printf() написать. Или функцию выделения динамической памяти. Ассемблер? Какой?

Comment: Объектные файлы - это машинный код после компиляции (формат, в котором он хранится, зависит от ОС: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)). *"взаимодействие с ОС"* - через [системные вызовы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а на каком языке пишутся выполнимые файлы? exe в Windows?

Comment: @AlexF Ну, я хотел услышать ответ Danny. Но если вы пишете exe руками в машинных кодах - то так же сможете написать и объектник :) Danny, объектные файлы - **результат компиляции**, в определенном смысле промежуточное представление программы между исходником и готовым выполнимым файлом. "Пишет" их компилятор. Возможно применение как С++, так и других языков программирования...

Comment: Если языком вы называете формат объектного файла, то в разных ОС по разному -- ELF, COFF, ECOFF, PE, Mach-O / Если вопрос о библиотеке (libc), которая лежит между ядром и большинством приложений на С++, то на  99.99% она написана на чистом Си